# Why is threeJS applyMatrix causing my console to go crazy and crash my browser?

Tags: javascript, three.js

This is based off a codepen that I am working on and I simplified the code to work with the specific part I need. I haven't worked with applyMatrix and Matrix4 before. For some reason the info from the part using these functions are showing up in my console and causing my browser to crash. I don't completely understand what is going on. I can guess that the values are being reassigned nonstop but I don't see a resolution to it in the codepen even though this issue isn't in it. Here is my code and the link to the codepen for reference.
https://codepen.io/Mamboleoo/pen/Bppdda?editors=0010
This codepen is out of my league and I am trying to get a better grasp of it.

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);

const spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xFFFFFF);
scene.add(spotLight);
spotLight.position.set(0, 0, 100);

spotLight.castShadow = true;
spotLight.angle = 0.2;
spotLight.intensity = 0.2;

camera.position.set(0.27, 0, 500);

//Black center
var geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 32, 32);
var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0x000000
});
var core = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);
scene.add(core);

var geom = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(1, 15, 15);
var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xffffff
});
var atoms = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(atoms);
for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
  var nucleus = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);
  var size = Math.random() * 6 + 1.5;
  nucleus.speedX = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.08;
  nucleus.speedY = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.08;
  nucleus.speedZ = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.08;
  nucleus.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(size, size, size));
  nucleus.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(0, 100 + Math.random() * 10, 0));
  nucleus.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(Math.random() * (Math.PI * 2)));
  nucleus.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(Math.random() * (Math.PI * 2)));
  nucleus.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(Math.random() * (Math.PI * 2)));
  atoms.add(nucleus);
}

function updateNucleus(a) {
  for (var i = 0; i < atoms.children.length; i++) {
    var part = atoms.children[i];
    part.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(part.speedX));
    part.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(part.speedY));
    part.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(part.speedZ));
  }
}

//Create scene
var necks = [];
var cubesObject = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(cubesObject);


function animate(a) {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    updateNucleus(a);
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
};

animate();

window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / this.window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> part.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(part.speedX));

The codepen uses an old version of `three.js` (`r79`). Since certain parts of the API have been renamed, the browser reports deprecation warnings every frame. With the latest version `r138`, the new code should look like so:

```js
part.applyMatrix4(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(part.speedX));
```

Besides, it's recommended that you don't create instances of `Matrix4` and other classes within the animation loop. Create the objects once outside of your loop and reuse them.

```js
const _matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
function updateNucleus(a) {
  for (var i = 0; i < atoms.children.length; i++) {
    var part = atoms.children[i];
    part.applyMatrix4(_matrix.makeRotationX(part.speedX));
    part.applyMatrix4(_matrix.makeRotationY(part.speedY));
    part.applyMatrix4(_matrix.makeRotationZ(part.speedZ));
  }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate this. I see you often in the threejs community, I appreciate your help